# Authenticating into Google App Engine from an iOS device

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, ios

I am working on an iPhone application that uses Google app engine to host the backend. I need to authenticate with Google but I can't seem to find a way to do it from my app. It seems I am down to making a `UIWebView` to have a user sign in to the redirected login page I am getting from Google, but I would much rather have the user enter there credentials one time and then have it persist, unless the user signs out.

Is this possible? Should I be looking at other options or am I just not handling the redirect correctly?

Any suggestions or info would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using OAuth?

Comment: I did, but it seemed like overkill. I have tracked down a framework called GoogleAppEngineAuth which handles getting an auth cookie. Now I am down to figuring out how to include that cookie in future requests.

Answer (score 5):

`O-Auth` is available on App Engine.
Just insert [GTMOAuth](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/) in your projet and present the `GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch`.  You'll be able to store the auth token in the user's keychain.

Then authorize your `NSURLMutableRequests` via `[auth authorizeRequest:myNSURLMutableRequest]`...
I think it might be easier than reusing and managing cookies.

Answer (score 0):

This page has pretty complete information on how to access the built-in Signin flow that is included with the generated app-engine endpoint library:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_ios