# Using the Google Toolbox for Mac OAuth for Google App Engine

Tags: iphone, ios, google-app-engine, oauth, google-toolbox-for-mac

I am trying to integrate an iOS application with Google App Engine using OAuth. I found that GTM has an OAuth Controller -- http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/

Can it be used to connect to Google App Engine? If so, what do I put as the "scope" parameter in

```
    - (id)initWithScope:(NSString *)scope
        language:(NSString *)language
  appServiceName:(NSString *)keychainAppServiceName
        delegate:(id)delegate 
finishedSelector:(SEL)finishedSelector;
```

I've tried to use my App Engine application's address (http://my-app-name.appspot.com) but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

btw this is sort of a follow up question to [Authenticating into Google App Engine from an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600844/authenticating-into-google-app-engine-from-an-ios-device).

Answer (score 3):

A late answer I know, but hopefully this will help someone:

**MYSITE** can be something like thunderofthor.com

Step 1:

Set up 2-legged OAuth for the App Engine domain of interest. To do this, log in as admin to https://www.google.com/a/MYSITE. Under advanced tools, click Manage OAuth domain key. Here, click 'Enable this consumer key' and 'Allow access to all APIs' to enable those options. On Google's side, you can now handle requests that use the **MYSITE** consumer key and the **OAUTHCONSUMERSECRET**.

Step 2:

In your servlet code, you can confirm the client has the correct credentials by requesting the OAuthConsumerKey which will be **MYSITE**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
String user = null;
try {
   OAuthService oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
   user = oauth.getOAuthConsumerKey();
   LOG.info("Authenticated: " + user);
} catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
    LOG.info("Not authenticated: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Step 3:

Download the [GTMOAuth](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/wiki/GTMOAuthIntroduction) package from Google. It will allow iOS to talk to your server effortlessly. You won't need the whole package for 2-legged auth. In fact, all you need is the GTMOAuthAuthentication files. To use in your code, do something like the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://MYSITE/dosomething"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc] initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1 consumerKey:@"MYSITE" privateKey:@"OAUTHCONSUMERSECRET"] ;
[auth setVersion:@"1.0"];

[auth addRequestTokenHeaderToRequest:request];

// Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

There! Effortless secure communication without requiring usernames and passwords!